# Table not extending full width of div?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table wrapped in a div that I need to scroll horizontally on mobile screens. I have that part working, but for some reason, on the right side of the table, I have a blank area making the table not extend to the full width of the wrapper div. Firefox reports that the table has the right pixel width, but it doesn't extend all the way like it is supposed to.

```css
.m-portlet__body {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.m-form {
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-portlet__body">
  <form name="user_notification">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Example of blank space:

[image: Blank Space]

Reported wrapper width:

[image: Wrapper Width]

Reported table width:

[image: Table Width]

Update with table width set to 100%:
[image]

Comment: You can move the min-width from `.m-form` to `.table`, 500px is too wide for mobile to be on the wrapper itself. You can also use a min-width of 100vw for the table.

Comment: You just need to give the table a width of 100%!

Comment: @SrishtiGupta I wish it were that easy!

Comment: @René the whole point is the actually be too wide. It is designed to scroll horizontally on mobile.

Comment: @SrishtiGupta is correct, it is that easy.  You are not telling the table anywhere in your css how wide it is supposed to be.  Therefore the table will only be as wide as it needs to be.  Thats how tables work.  You need to make the tables width 100% if you want it to be as wide as its container.  I inspected the code snippet above, added 100% and it fills the parent container.

Comment: @sn3ll I checked in a Codepin and it does indeed work. Now the question is as to why it does not work in my environment.

Comment: @KeatonBurleson That is why we need a [mcve]

Comment: @LGSon ..I have here. I cannot find any other CSS affecting these elements. This is the bare minimum in a complicated webapp.

Comment: @KeatonBurleson Obviously not we got a _MCVE_, as the posted sample behave if the width is the to 100%, which you say doesn't in your own environment. We can't solve issues we don't see.

Comment: Understandable.  A wild guess would be look for a parent that has a display or position property set to something weird.

Comment: @AsiyaFatima Please do not add deprecated tags to questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

CSS:

```
 .m-portlet__body{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
 }
 .m-form{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    min-width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
 }
 .table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    th:first-child{
        width: 350px;
    }
    th{
        width: 100px;
    }

    td{
        width: 100px;
    }
 }
```

HTML remained unchanged.

I still do not know WHY it does not work as everyone else (and I, in a codepin) reported. I checked every single parent element and removed anything out of the ordinary, stripping it down. This works fine, still weird through.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried applying the `100%` with to table columns?

Sometimes, it would be easier to troubleshoot if you could prepare the demo on #jsfiddle or #Codepen.

Comment: that actually makes the columns smaller

Comment: I mean use something like: `width: calc(100% - 5px); min-width:100px;`. Hope that helps!